# Getting a gl error when trying to install gpu.js

Tags: node.js, gpu.js

I'm trying to install gpu.js, but I keep getting error:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/lukelin/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.18.2 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=darwin)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.18.2 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lukelin/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/lukelin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/lukelin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/lukelin/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.18.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/lukelin/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last):
npm ERR!   File "/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 42, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp  # noqa: E402
npm ERR!     ^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR!   File "/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
npm ERR!     import gyp.input
npm ERR!   File "/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 19, in <module>
npm ERR!     from distutils.version import StrictVersion
npm ERR! ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/lukelin/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/lukelin/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node" "/Users/lukelin/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/lukelin/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.18.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/lukelin/.npm/_logs/2023-12-19T04_33_03_390Z-debug-0.log
```

- Operating System: MacOS 10.15.7
- Node.js Version : 18.18.2
- Npm Version: 10.2.3

I also tried Yarn and Bun, but they also throw the similar error. I also tried to install it on my Linux server, but it also failed (The same error).